# Transfering UV and more after retopolgy

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, retopology

Some time ago i decided to finally buy Quad remesh , so i can work with light versions of super duper heavy characters in animations.

But after remeshing those , all data ( uv , textures ) are of course lost  , so i'm looking data transfer videos,  the fews solutions i found to transfer those back to a mesh with different topology did not seem to work for me ,( it's hard to find information on the subject because it's flooded with results linked to the term "retopology " )

What would be the workflow for that? Right after i am done with retopology , having myself a clean model , but all white.

Comment: Hello, you need to bake the diffuse from the high-poly to the low-poly